# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with WHERE condition and more than 50 fields

Tags: mysql, insert-update

```
INSERT INTO table1 SET 
field1=aa, 
field2=bb, 
field3=cc 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET 
  field1 = IF( field4 = zz, aa, field1 ),
  field2 = IF( field4 = zz, bb,    field2 ),
  field3 = IF( field4 = zz, cc, field3 );
```

This is ok, but i do have 50+ fields to update and all of them requires one same condition to update, do i really need to do this for all or is there any better solution ....?

Comment: Are aa,bb,cc,zz fields or strings?

Comment: You can try separate inserts, and wrap then using a transaction. That way they are sent to the server all at once.

Comment: @P.Salmon - field1,field2,field3 are columns only here

Comment: @DanIonescu - could u please post query here? it would help to understand the way